# how to sort integer from listFiles?

Tags: java

I want to sort the integer from listFiles which not included the string. The smallest number will display"The smallest number=" and the biggest number will display"The biggest number="

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File folder = new File("input/");
        File [] files = folder.listFiles();         

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length-1;i++) {

            String fileFullName = files[i].getName();       
            String fileSimple= fileFullName.substring(2,fileFullName.length()-4);           
            long fileNumber =Long.parseLong(fileSimple);

            String fileFullName2 = files[i+1].getName();        
            String fileSimple2= fileFullName2.substring(2,fileFullName2.length()-4);            
            long fileNumber2 =Long.parseLong(fileSimple2);                  
        }                       
    }
```

The file name included HR20190405.txt, AR20290405.txt,RG20290805.txt,RK21290405.txt

Comment: Why do you handle two files in your loop body? And where is the part of the code which calculates the min/max values? Or if you want all the numbers sorted, you should use some kind of collection. We can only help you, if you make clear, where your problem exactly is.

Comment: Do you want to sort `files` array by integer value from file name?

Answer (score 1):

There is suitable method [`summaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--) from `IntStream`. Using stream api it will look like:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stat = Arrays.stream(files)
        .mapToInt(file -> Integer.valueOf(file.getName().substring(2, file.getName().length() - 4)))
        .summaryStatistics();

System.out.println(stat.getMin());
System.out.println(stat.getMax());
```

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close. We will just have to store the maximum & minimum values in variables. Also, the code to fetch the number from file name can be a separate method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folder = new File("input/");
    File [] files = folder.listFiles();      

    //Set first number as smallest and largest   
    long smallest = getNumberFromName(files[0]);
    long largest = smallest;

    //Get number for each file and assign smallest & largest values
    for(int i = 1; i < files.length-1;i++) {
        long nextNumber = getNumberFromName(files[i]);
        if (smallest > nextNumber)
            smallest = nextNumber
        if (largest < nextNumber)
            largest = nextNumber
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest number="+smallest)
    System.out.println("The biggest number="+largest)
}


private static long getNumberFromName(File nextFile) {
    String fileFullName = nextFile.getName();       
    String fileSimple= fileFullName.substring(2,fileFullName.length()-4);           
    return Long.parseLong(fileSimple);
}
```

Comment: It just display the correct smallest but the largest incorrect  which display the middle.

Comment: well, then something else is going on. if the input list is not very large can you comment it here and what is the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Actually based on a previous answer, you can go even further and refine the code to use both the Stream API as well as `java.nio`. This will save you plenty of time as you won't be needing to perform manual iterations over the array of files you have read.

Also a good trick is to avoid the various magic number during substringing actions. A regex would have been way more suitable to avoid unwanted runtime errors.

Based on the above, a sample code would look like:

```
private static Optional<IntSummaryStatistics> getMinMax(final String filePath) {
    try (Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.list(Paths.get(filePath))){
        return Optional.of(pathStream
        .map(Path::getFileName)
        .map(Path::toString)
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+",""))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .summaryStatistics());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

And calling this would as simple as doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getMinMax("D:\\test").ifPresentOrElse(
        stats -> System.out.println("Min is " + stats.getMin() + " Max is " + stats.getMax()),
        () -> System.out.println("Nothing has been found")
    );
}
```